# csv to complex nested json

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

So, I have a huge CSV file that looks like:

```
PN,PCA Code,MPN Code,DATE_CODE,Supplier Code,CM Code,Fiscal YEAR,Fiscal MONTH,Usage,Defects
13-1668-01,73-2590,MPN148,1639,S125,CM1,2017,5,65388,0
20-0127-02,73-2171,MPN170,1707,S125,CM1,2017,9,11895,0
19-2472-01,73-2302,MPN24,1711,S119,CM1,2017,10,4479,0
20-0127-02,73-2169,MPN170,1706,S125,CM1,2017,9,7322,0
20-0127-02,73-2296,MPN170,1822,S125,CM1,2018,12,180193,0
15-14399-01,73-2590,MPN195,1739,S133,CM6,2018,11,1290,0
```

What I want to do is group up all the data by PCA Code. So, a PCA Code will have certain number for parts, those parts would be manufactured by certain MPN Code and the final nested JSON structure that I want looks like:

```json
[
    {
        PCA: {
            "code": "73-2590",
            "CM": ["CM1", "CM6"],
            "parts": [
                {
                    "number": "13-1668-01",
                    "manufacturer": [
                        {
                            "id": "MPN148"
                            "info": [
                                {
                                    "date_code": 1639,
                                    "supplier": {
                                        "id": "S125",
                                        "FYFM": "2020-9",
                                        "usage": 65388,
                                        "defects": 0,
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

So, I want this structure for multiple part numbers (PNs) having different MPNs with different Date Codes and so on.

I am currently using Pandas to do this but I'm stuck on how to proceed with the nesting.

My code so far:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv('files/dppm_wc.csv')

data = {'PCAs': []}

for key, group in dataframe.groupby('PCA Code'):
    for index, row in group.itterrows():
        temp_dict = {'PCA Code': key, 'CM Code': row['CM Code'], 'parts': []}

with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

How do I proceed to achieve the nested JSON format that I want? Is there a better way to do this than what I am doing?

Comment: The information required to define the nesting is not inherent in the data file.  Rather, it is your artificial imposition.  Therefore, you will need to manually code the nesting logic.  "I'm stuck" is not a Stack Overflow issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you wish to do with that structure, but I guess it could be achieved with something like this

```py
data = {'PCAs': []}

for key, group in df.groupby('PCA Code'):
    temp_dict = {'PCA Code': key, 'CM Code': [], 'parts': []}
    for index, row in group.iterrows():
        temp_dict['CM Code'].append(row['CM Code'])
        temp_dict['parts'].append(
            {'number': row['PN'], 
             'manufacturer': [
                 {
                     'id': row['MPN Code'], 
                     'info': [
                         {
                             'date_code': row['DATE_CODE'], 
                             'supplier': {'id': row['Supplier Code'], 
                                          'FYFM': '%s-%s' % (row['Fiscal YEAR'], row['Fiscal MONTH']), 
                                          'usage': row['Usage'], 
                                          'defects': row['Defects']}
                         }
                     ]
                 }]
             }
        )
    data['PCAs'].append(temp_dict)
```